# Accessing model's owner in their create method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my application, I have a model for a `note`, which is a block of text belonging to a `patient`. I'm trying to make it such that when you navigate to a `patient`'s `show`, you have the ability to add a `note` to that patient which will be displayed on the `show`. I was easily able to generate notes for a patient in `seeds.rb` and make them display on the `show`, but my issue is with creating new `notes`.

I know that the meat of the answer is going to be in the `create` method in `notes_controller.rb`, though I'm not exactly sure how to grab the `patient_id` upon creation.

It will look *something* like this

```
def create
 @note = current_patient.notes.build(note_params)
 if @note.save
  #update current page? also wondering how to do this
 else
  flash[:alert] = "Failed"
 end 
end
```

My problem is that I don't actually have a `current_patient` method and I'm not sure how to make one. Any guidance would be amazing. I'll post some possibly relevant snippets below.

`patient.rb`

```
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner
  has_many :stays
  has_many :notes
  belongs_to :feed_list
  validates :name, 
    presence: true, 
    length: { maximum: 50 }, 
    uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false}

 #......
end
```

`note.rb`

```
class Note < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :patient
  validates :patient_id, presence: true
  default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
  validates :content, presence: true
end
```

Comment: Google around for Rails nested attributes and nested forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you could include nested routes in your routes declarations:

```
resources :patients do
  resources :notes
end
```

Then in your `notes_controller.rb`, you can look for your patient id like this:

```
def create
 @patient = Patient.find(params[:patient_id])
 @note = @patient.notes.build(note_params)
 if @note.save
  #update current page? also wondering how to do this
 else
  flash[:alert] = "Failed"
 end 
end
```

Comment: thanks, this seems to be a step in the right direction. I'm now getting a routing error but I'll look at that separately. Upvoting for helpfulness